Stripe API itemized capture/cancel
I'm currently using the Stripe payments API to authorize and delay capture/cancel payments but I'm wondering if it is possible to capture a fee and capture/cancel individual products/items/line-items.
I see the API allows for products, price objects and application fee, but I'm having trouble finding documentation on whether or not products/line-items can be individually captured and cancelled. Would I need to use the invoice API or is it possible with the payments/checkout API?
Or is the solution to create a payment intent and then update the intent to edit products in the transaction by incrementing the authorization?
To give a little more detail, I have a payment requirement where customer submit a form for several services (products). I'm looking to charge a fee for each request (captured on form submit) and the services are individually captured if approved, or cancelled if declined, in a single payment intent object (order).

As far as I'm aware, multi-capture is possible with Stripe, but not publicly. You would have to reach out to them to know if you can avail of that feature.
Publicly, you can only capture a payment once - fully or partially. It's also not item-based, but by raw amounts only - you would need a logic that infers the itemized amount and passes it in the capture:
https://docs.stripe.com/payments/place-a-hold-on-a-payment-method#capture-funds
About your project as a whole, if you can't avail of multi-capture, then you would need to create multiple payment intents. I would recommend saving the card with the initial payment (the quote submission), then creating one or more payment_intents off session to charge for the products - with capture_method=manual.
I appreciate it's not great, but it's the only solution I'm aware of.
(Btw Stripe Invoicing doesn't support manual capture)

Thanks for the info, what about using the “Application Fee” object? https://docs.stripe.com/api/application_fees

Unless there's something I don't know about your use-case, Application Fees are irrelevant to this context. They are an amount that's retained by a Connect platform when the payment goes through them. Its presence has no impact on how the capture works.

good to know, do you know if there is any way to add your own transaction fee to an authorization?
